# List of data tables of different dimensions from a grouped data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) like this:

```r
# Load data table package
library(data.table)

# Create dummy data
dt <- data.table(grp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 3), 
                 val = 1:9)

# Peek
dt
#>    grp val
#> 1:   A   1
#> 2:   A   2
#> 3:   A   3
#> 4:   B   4
#> 5:   B   5
#> 6:   B   6
#> 7:   C   7
#> 8:   C   8
#> 9:   C   9
```

I'd like to apply a function to `val` grouped by `grp`. The result will be a data table, but the dimensions of the data table will differ for each group. Consequently, I don't think I can do this *within* `[]` because of the inconsistent dimensions, so I use `by`.

**NOTE**: I just use a dummy function to produce data tables of different size for demonstration purposes.

```r
# Seed RNG
set.seed(-1)

# Run by
res <- with(dt, by(val, grp, function(x) data.table(diag(sample(x, 1)))))

# Peek 
res
#> grp: A
#>    V1 V2 V3
#> 1:  1  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0
#> 3:  0  0  1
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> grp: B
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> 1:  1  0  0  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0  0  0
#> 3:  0  0  1  0  0
#> 4:  0  0  0  1  0
#> 5:  0  0  0  0  1
#> -------------------------------------------------------- 
#> grp: C
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#> 1:  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 3:  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 4:  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#> 5:  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
#> 6:  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
#> 7:  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
#> 8:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
#> 9:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

My desired result is a list of these data tables, as shown below:

```r
# Desired result
lapply(names(res), function(x)res[[x]])
#> [[1]]
#>    V1 V2 V3
#> 1:  1  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0
#> 3:  0  0  1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> 1:  1  0  0  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0  0  0
#> 3:  0  0  1  0  0
#> 4:  0  0  0  1  0
#> 5:  0  0  0  0  1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
#> 1:  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 2:  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 3:  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#> 4:  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
#> 5:  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
#> 6:  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
#> 7:  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
#> 8:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
#> 9:  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My question: is there a way to achieve this in all in one step, rather than using `by` then restructuring the `by` object into a list?

Comment: You can use `split` `lapply(split(dt$val, dt$grp), function(x) data.table(diag(sample(x, 1))))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done within `data.table`, if we wrap in a `list`

```
dt[, .(list(data.table(diag(sample(val, 1))))), grp]
```

Comment: Since `.` is a `list` short-hand, you can collapse to `dt[, .(.(data.table(diag(sample(val, 1))))), grp]` too.